# What necessary changes are required to pass String using reference

Tags: c++, string, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm designing a user defined String Compare function using "Pass by Reference" in C++.

My code is working fine when passing a pointer to the first character, but I'm struggling to pass the argument by reference. This is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>

int StrCmp(char [], int, char []);
int main()
{
char Str1[100], Str2[100];
int Compare = 0, StrSize1 = 10; //Both strings are having same number of alphabets.

std::cout<<"Input the First String: "<<std::endl;
gets(Str1);
std::cout<<"Input the Second String: "<<std::endl;
gets(Str2);

     Compare = StrCmp(Str1, StrSize1, Str2);

if (Compare == 1)
    std::cout<<"String 1 *"<<Str1<<"* is Greater Than String 2 *"<<Str2<<"*"<<std::endl;
else if(Compare == -1)
    std::cout<<"String 1 *"<<Str1<<"* is Smaller Than String 2 *"<<Str2<<"*"<<std::endl;
else if(Compare == 0)
    std::cout<<"Both String 1 *"<<Str1<<"* and String 2 *"<<Str2<<"* are Equal"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int StrCmp(char PassedStr1[], int Size1, char PassedStr2[])
{
    for(int i=0; i<Size1 ; ++i)
    {
        int CodeAscii_1 = PassedStr1[i];
        int CodeAscii_2 = PassedStr2[i];

        if(CodeAscii_1 > CodeAscii_2)
            return 1;
        else if(CodeAscii_1 < CodeAscii_2)
            return -1;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone please help me understand what necessary changes I need to do to make the code work for passing the argument by reference. 
Thanks

Comment: Side note: `gets` is so unsafe that it's been removed from both C and C++. In C++, you'd normally read a `std::string` with `std::getline`. If C strings are required, `fgets`.

Comment: You are not passing the entire string currently. You are passing a pointer to the first character (of a C style string). I think you probably need to understand pointers and arrays a little better. Then you would see that there is no possible reason to pass a pointer by reference in this case.

Comment: @chris thanks for the suggestion . I'll keep that in mind from now onwards.

Comment: @john you guess it right . I'm completely a newbie into programming. Sorry for the mistake tho.  Can you suggest a place to understand pointers and arrays better?

Comment: @NoorMohammad Well a quick google found this https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2010/readings/pointers.pdf it's for the C language but the treatment of arrays and pointers is the same in C and C++. Chapter 4 seems to cover the issues raised by your question.

Comment: @john thank u so much. really appreciated tht

Comment: To pass a string, in C++, to functions, use `std::string`.  You can pass by copy or use '&' to pass by reference.

Comment: BTW, there is no need for `int` in your `StrCmp` function.  Since the parameters are of type `char` (specifically pointers to `char`), you should use `char` as the type for the local variables.  Also, make them `const`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass C style arrays by reference in C++ to avoid having them decay into pointers but you need to tell the compiler exactly the fixed size of the array you're passing. Here is an example declaration for your two arrays.

```
int StrCmp(const char (&PassedStr1)[100], const char (&PassedStr2)[100]);
```